# How to paginate and show all records using hasMany in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables one table for general information about the order named `orders`  and a `detail` table for information like products, notes and delivery date.

Basically, I want to show in the same page the table orders and for each order can be multiple products, notes, dates from the table detail, and also I want to paginate in order to show exactly 20 orders on each page and every product, note, date row with the same id_order.

In conclusion, on each page there are 20 orders from table orders  but  there can be 40 rows from table detail with products, notes, delivery date, because one order can contain more than one product. in fact I want to use rowspan html in order to show on the same row the detail.

This is my **Orders model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class order extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['client','number_order','file'];

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Detail','orders_id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
}
```

**Detail model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Detail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'detail';

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Detail','orders_id');
    }
}
```

My **controller**:

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::first(); //This works only with one record I cant show all records, all() is not working

    $orders->setRelation('details', $orders->details()->paginate(10));

    return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

**View**:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($orders->details as $detail)
        <tr id="{{ $detail->orders_id }}">
            <td>{{ $detail->product }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use eager load details on order like this

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::with('details')->paginate(20);
    return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

In view

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($orders as $order)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $order->created_at }}</td>
            <td>... put any order info here</td>
            <td>
                <label>Order Details:</label>
                <table>
                    @foreach ($order->details as $detail)
                        <tr id="{{ $detail->orders_id }}">
                            <td>{{ $detail->product }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $detail->note }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            <td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```